# How to make activity indicator to animate during api call in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I had placed an activity indicator on view in storyboard and will work when during loading and works fine but after loading the screen then when I click on an item in content view then the api call goes on during that time in this time I need to make activity indicator to animate on content view can anyone help me how to make activity indicator to run on content view during api call ?

Here is my layout for the screen

[image]

Comment: **I need to make activity indicator to animate on content view but it is running on view can anyone help me how to make activity indicator to run on content view during api call ?** Pls explain this!

Comment: I don't want to use another activity indicator will I able to use it during my api call during the content view to display @dahiya_boy

Comment: while loading view I need to use on view after completion of loading I need to display activity indicator when I click on item for api call then at that time I need to display activity indicator animation @dahiya_boy

Comment: Then start `activityindictaor` befor API call and when you got data stop `activityindictaor`

Comment: I had done making activity indicator before api call but it was running on background of view but I need it to display on content view ? @dahiya_boy

Comment: Is there any issue if you take new `activityIndicator` in the containerView and animate it according to requirement.

Comment: no not a problem already I am trying like that but the problem here is activity indicator also moving up with content view @dahiya_boy here I had given constraints also

Comment: Yeah it move with the container. If you wanted to show activityIndicator in the screen and it not move then use the activityIndicator which you already added .

Comment: I already said that if I use the previous one it is running on the view and the content view is top on it so unable to see on ui @dahiya_boy

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the activity Indicator into the Content View subsection in your interface builder.

Comment: but it should be centre if I move in my content view also will it work for that ?

Comment: I think it will be central to the content view, but i'm not sure. Give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

First, connect the UI Properties

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityView:UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView:UIView!
```

Just drag the activity Indicator into the Content View subsection in your interface builder and set the centre

```
activityView.center = contentView.center
```

Start animating when calling API

```
activityView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: if I place it on centre the activity indicator is going down because my content view height is about 1170

Comment: then try to put the centre as view centre : activityView.center = self.view.center

Answer (score 0):

Change your view Hierarchy like the below one

[image]

Comment: I tried with that also but content view will be there so activity indicator will not be visible

Comment: @user0246 Can you pls describe what is the actual issue you'r facing?

Comment: I need to place activity indicator during api call and it should be in center like as shown in image and it need to set for all devices in centre